# Ryzen vs. i7 Multi-Threaded Performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu

I made the following C# Console App:

```
    class Program
    {
        static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> StateCount { get; set; }
        static int length = 1000000000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StateCount = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                StateCount.AddOrUpdate(i, 0, (k, v) => 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Processors: " + Environment.ProcessorCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Timer t = new Timer(1000);
            t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
            t.Start();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Parallel.For(0, length, (i) =>
            {
                var rand = GetRandomNumber();
                int newState = 0;
                if(rand < 0.3)
                {
                    newState = 0;
                }
                else if (rand < 0.6)
                {
                    newState = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    newState = 2;
                }
                StateCount.AddOrUpdate(newState, 0, (k, v) => v + 1);
            });
            sw.Stop();
            t.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if(StateCount.TryGetValue(i, out int value))
                {
                    total += value;
                }
            }
            int percent = (int)Math.Round((total / (double)length) * 100);
            Console.Write("\r" + percent + "%");
        }

        public static double GetRandomNumber()
        {
            var bytes = new Byte[8];
            rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            var ul = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0) / (1 << 11);
            Double randomDouble = ul / (Double)(1UL << 53);
            return randomDouble;
        }
    }
```

Before running this, the Task Manager reported <2% CPU usage (across all runs and machines).

I ran it on a machine with a Ryzen 3800X. The output was:

Processors: 16
Total time: 209.22

The speed reported in the Task Manager while it ran was ~4.12 GHz.

I ran it on a machine with an i7-7820HK The output was:

Processors: 8
Total time: 213.09

The speed reported in the Task Manager while it ran was ~3.45 GHz.

I modified Parallel.For to include the processor count (`Parallel.For(0, length, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, (i) => {code});`). The outputs were:

3800X: 16 - 158.58 @ ~4.13

7820HK: 8 - 210.49 @ ~3.40

There's something to be said about `Parallel.For` not natively identifying the Ryzen processors vs cores, but setting that aside, even here the Ryzen performance is still significantly poorer than would be expected (only ~25% faster with double the cores/processors, a faster speed, and larger L1-3 caches). Can anyone explain why?

Edit: Following a couple of comments, I made some changes to my code. See below:

```
static int length = 1000;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StateCount = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                StateCount.AddOrUpdate(i, 0, (k, v) => 0);
            }
            var procCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Console.WriteLine("Processors: " + procCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            List<double> times = new List<double>();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                Parallel.For(0, length, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = procCount }, (i) =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
                    {
                        var rand = GetRandomNumber();
                        int newState = 0;
                        if (rand < 0.3)
                        {
                            newState = 0;
                        }
                        else if (rand < 0.6)
                        {
                            newState = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newState = 2;
                        }
                        StateCount.AddOrUpdate(newState, 0, (k, v) => v + 1);
                    }
                });
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Total time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            var avg = times.Average();
            var variance = times.Select(x => (x - avg) * (x - avg)).Sum() / times.Count;
            var stdev = Math.Sqrt(variance);
            Console.WriteLine("Average time: " + avg  + " +/- " + stdev);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The outside loop is 1,000 instead of 1,000,000,000, so there are "only" 1,000 parallel "tasks." Within each parallel "task" however there's now a loop of 1,000,000 actions, so the act of "getting the task" or whatever should have a much smaller affect on the total. I also loop the whole thing 10 times and get the average + standard devation. Output:

Ryzen 3800X: 158.531 +/- 0.429 @ ~4.13

i7-7820HK: 202.159 +/- 2.538 @ ~3.48

Even here, the Ryzen's twice as many threads and 0.60 GHz higher clock only result in a ~75% faster time for the total operation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223680/discussion-on-question-by-eternal-ambiguity-ryzen-vs-i7-multi-threaded-performa).